# send value of a variable to other page

Tags: javascript

```
side_bar_html += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'>" + place.name + "</br></a></br> Address   :  " + place.vicinity +"</br>Distance : " + google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(centralLocation, place.geometry.location).toFixed(2) + " meters</br></br><input type= button OnClick='window.location.href = \"explore-map2.jsp?key=40.68509,-73.84357\"'; value = Locate&nbsp;&nbsp;Direction><br/></br/>"
```

I have the value of lat and long in a variable `place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)` and i want to send the value of key `place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)` instead of static lat long in key which is `key=40.68509,-73.84357`(above). I have tried it but there is some syntax error coming up.
Please tell me how do i send the value of key as `place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)` to `explore-map2.jsp` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use encodeURIComponent() function to sanitize key=40.68509,-73.84357

Example :

explore-map2.jsp?key=encodeURIComponent("40.68509,-73.84357")